# Alter AttributeSet values in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-custom-attributes

I am having custom view which will take attribute set(xml value) as constructor value

```
public CustomView(Context context)  // No Attributes in this one.
{
    super(context);
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this(context, attrs, 0)
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int default_style) {
    super(context, attrs, default_style);
    readAttrs(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}
```

In Fragment class i am setting the view as

```
CustomView customView = (CustomView) view.findViewById(R.id.customView);
```

where custom view contains various value such as height,width,padding etc.

i want to modify those values based on required condition and set it back to custom view.
I placed setting width height code in **onDraw** method and called invalidte view.
But above method will set the  every time if i called **invalidate** method in CustomView class.
how to overcome this so that i can pass modified attribute set value in constructor only.?

**Edit**: I need to modify the view values(initialize with new values) which is set during attribute constructor so that i will get a refreshed view with a new values.
Override @OnDraw  or 'Invalidate' is not a good function for me where inside invalidate i have written the methods which will execute in each second interval.

Comment: In stead try setting `LayoutParams` for you `CustomView`. that way you can modify its values based on required condition.

Comment: @astuter The CustomView values are not only width,height etc. The values which are defined in view such as color,showText,ShowColor,ShowGraph. etc.

Answer (score 2):

I see that your `CustomView` can have multiple attributes and you want to modify some of these attributes based on some condition and pass this in the constructor.

Few best practices while designing a custom view:

1. If you have custom attributes, make sure that you expose them via setters and getters. In your setter method, call `invalidate();`
2. Don't try modifying any attributes inside `onDraw()` or `onMeasure()` methods.
3. Try your best to avoid writing Custom constructors for your Custom View.

So the ideal way to solve your problem is to instantiate your CustomView and then modify the attributes, either externally (in your Activity or Fragment), or have a method inside the `CustomView.java` and then invoke it externally. Doing this will still give you the same result you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. That is what i am looking for. I need to modify custom attribute values so that i can invalidate my views to reflect in.

Comment: I would suggest that you have a method inside the CustomView that does the conditional check that you want (if it's generic), and based on that modify your attributes via the setter methods for your attributes. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the solution you were hoping for, but put a **FrameLayout** in your xml instead of the **CustomView**, and then create your **CustomView** programmatically with the **FrameLayout** as it's parent

Comment: Thanks. My problem is need to pass custom parameter such as Customview.angle,customView.isIntialized like parameters which is previously set in attributeset xml..

Answer (score 0):

So lets say you declared your custom attributes like this for view named StarsView

```
<declare-styleable name="StarsView">
    <attr name="stars" format="integer" />
    <attr name="score" format="float" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And you want to read attributes from something like this

```
<my.package..StarsView
    app:stars="5"
    app:score="4.6"
```

You do just this in constructor

```
public StarsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if(attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.StarsView, defStyleAttr, 0);
        stars = Tools.MathEx.clamp(1, 10, a.getInt(R.styleable.StarsView_stars, 5));
        score =  (int)Math.floor(a.getFloat(R.styleable.StarsView_score, stars) * 2f);
        a.recycle(); // its important to call recycle after we are done
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading is fine in my case; The problem is i need to alter the value based on condition and refresh only those values.
Ex: I have ten attributes and i need to alter only two attributes and should refresh view.

Comment: i think i dont get it a bit, AttributeSet you receive while constructing view is just Android way of allowing you to read XML writted values, and of course when i read my stars = 5, and what to write in textView 5 i would just set this value when i create set View

Comment: also add set / get methods for your variables that represent this attributes in your view, so you can alter them trought code